# How to delete a function on which a cursor is in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, evil, deletion, sexp

Let's say I have this:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (my-func|tion 5) (my-function-2 "hello")
  (third-function-of-mine nil))
```

where | is my cursor.

And I want to delete (my-function 5).

So in the end I will have this:

```
(defn -main [& args]
   | (my-function-2 "hello")
  (third-function-of-mine nil))
```

So basically I need to kill the whole function including the parentheses.

How to do that in Spacemacs or Emacs? I am using evil mode, but even if you are using the standard shortcuts any help is appreciated.

Comment: In this case, you can just delete the paren text object.  Assuming standard keybindings, it would be `da(`.

Comment: `C-M-u C-M-n C-w` should do it with vanilla emacs.  For the first two keybindings, see [Moving in the Parenthesis Structure](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-by-Parens.html) (or, better, read it in Emacs itself: `C-h i g(emacs)RET i paren TAB` should take you to the same section of the manual). The third, `C-w`, is the standard `kill-region` command.

Comment: `[ m w` if `lispy` is active ;-)